# MongoDB - how to perform consecutive queries?

Tags: mongodb, filtering

I have a schema where one field is an array of values. The collection might look something like:

```
{
  _id: 1,
  tags: ['a', 'b']
},
{
  _id: 2, 
  tags: ['b', 'a']
},
  _id: 3,
  tags: ['a', 'c']
},
  _id: 4,
  tags: ['c', 'd']
},
  _id:5,
  tags: ['b', 'e']
}
```

The user should be able to perform consecutive filter operations, for example,

1. Filtering for 'a' will return _id:1, _id:2, and _id:3;
2. A consecutive filter for 'b' will return _id:1 and _id:2 (presumably from the results of step 1 above).

There might be n number of consecutive filter operations.

What is the best way to structure this filter with Mongodb?

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: Isn't this a simple `AND`? What is the programing language you take the user input, do you use any framework? What is providing the interaction?

Comment: @DanielW. Yes it can be but I am wondering if that is the best approach. No framework, just javascript for now. The interaction is a search input bar. At the moment I can use `Test.find({tags:{$all: ["a"]}})` then `Test.find({tags:{$all: ["a", "b"]}})` but this and any subsequent filter operations are searching the entire DB.

Comment: You can put each result in memory (in a variable) and apply filter to that instead of querying the database. But I don't know if I'd do that since your tags should have indices the server shouldn't bother.

Comment: Thanks @DanielW. Are you suggesting the result be saved client or server side? The data should be small in size and non-senstive (just tag names and associated links).

Comment: I'd suggest to not store the results in memory because the database is already doing that. Use `Test.find({tags:{$all: ["a", "b"]}})`.